F11 shows desktop. When I assign another key, it resets after login
I have a clean install of Sequoia on my new MBP. I use function keys a lot (IBM iSeries 5250 emulation, very old school). Therefore I changed the standard mapping for "Show Desktop" which defaults to F11 to not be assigned. That works. Until I log out and log in again.... Every time after logging in, the Show Desktop has shortcut F11 assigned again.
Is this a bug more people are experiencing?
Update: I have the setting enabled to use function keys as such, of course.
